# How can I solve a deprecated View method in Android?

Tags: java, android

I built the Tic Tac Toe Android app. When I click play again to restart a new game I am facing a crash.

[image: Screenshot of logcat]

Comment: I added the crash image above , thank you for your help

Comment: Would you provide your MainActivity.java?

Comment: [This article](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) about images of exceptions is a very useful read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've tried to cast "android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout" into "android.widget.GridLayout".

Inside code line 102 in your main activity (from your error that you added). You can't cast that and that is why your app got crashed.

If you want things to work for you - decide if you want to use grid layout or the support grid layout and use it without the other (if you chose option a you need to cast it to option a and the contrary).

Comment: thank you very much I will try to implement your suggestions.

Comment: I tried above suggestion , my code works perfectly without crashing. Thank you a lot

Comment: If that helped you please mark my answer as accepted so other can see it and follow it in case of samw problem.